# global var becomes local --UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment

Tags: python

I initialized `rate` as a global var:

```
import os, sys
rate=30

def foo():
    print('#########rate:', rate)
    if False:
        rate=int(sys.argv[2])


foo()
```

but when running the script, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Line 10, in <module>
    foo()
  Line 5, in foo
    print('#########rate:', rate)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'rate' referenced before assignment
```

although the `if False: rate=int(sys.argv[2])` statement is not executed, it seems has some influence, is there some python rules explains this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should declare `rate` as global:

```
import os, sys
rate=30

def foo():
    global rate # <----
    print('#########rate:', rate)
    if False:
        rate=int(sys.argv[2])


foo()
```

If there is assignment to a varaint (without global declaration), it is treated as local variable.

Comment: Might be worth explaining [why](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value)

Comment: why it becomes local even that expression is not executed?

Comment: @zhangxaochen, If there is assignment to a varaint (without global declaration), it is treated as local variable.